# How to join one column to two columns in other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have really tough problem with one select that is bothering me since 11A.M. so what do I mean,
I have two tables named Lotnisko and Loty [ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpYFV.png), as shown on the picture.

That's how the tables are looking:

**Where Lotnisko means Airport /// Loty means Flights /// NumerLotu is FlightNumber /// MiejsceOdlotu is place of departure /// MiejscePrzylotu is place of arrival**

My best select for now is this [Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSwT7.png)

```
select Loty.NumerLotu as [Numer Lotu], Lotnisko.Nazwa as [Miejsce Odlotu]
from Loty
JOIN Lotnisko on Loty.MiejsceOdlotu = Lotnisko.LotniskoID
where NumerLotu = 'KL1995'
```

---

```
select Loty.NumerLotu as [Numer Lotu], Lotnisko.Nazwa as [Miejsce Przylotu]
from Loty
JOIN Lotnisko on Loty.MiejscePrzylotu = Lotnisko.LotniskoID
where NumerLotu = 'KL1995'
```

Which is giving me this result: [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ohpsf.png)

What do I want? I want result in one select, best one I've got is this:

```
select Loty.NumerLotu as [Numer Lotu], Lotnisko.Nazwa as [Miejsce Odlotu], Lotnisko.Nazwa as [Miejsce Przylotu]
from Loty
JOIN Lotnisko on Loty.MiejsceOdlotu = Lotnisko.LotniskoID
JOIN Lotnisko przylot on Loty.MiejscePrzylotu = przylot.LotniskoID
where NumerLotu = 'KL1995'
```

This is the result: [Result2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPFyn.png)

I want to have this in output:

| Numer Lotu | Miejsce odlotu | Miejsce Przylotu |
| --- | --- | --- |
| KL1995 | Port lotniczy Amsterdam-Schiphol | Port lotniczy Kraków-Balice |

Comment: Your `SELECT` needed to change the table used for the third output to `przylot` for example `przylot.Nazwa as [Miejsce Przylotu]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward. Just use the (optional) `AS` keyword in your joins, and refer to the tables with that in your `SELECT`.

```sql
SELECT
    t1.Numer_Lotu AS "Numer Lotu",
    t1.Miejsce_Odlotu AS "Miejsce Odlotu",
    t2.Miejsce_Przylotu AS "Miejsce Przylotu"
FROM Loty
INNER JOIN Lotnisko AS t1
    ON Loty.MiejsceOdlotu = t1.LotniskoID
INNER JOIN Lotnisko AS t2
    ON Loty.MiejscePrzylotu = t2.LotniskoID
WHERE NumerLotu = 'KL1995'
```

Comment: I edited it a little and it's working, thanks!

`SELECT
 Loty.NumerLotu AS "Numer Lotu",
 l1.Nazwa as "Miejsce Odlotu",
 l2.Nazwa as "Miejsce Przylotu"
FROM Loty
JOIN Lotnisko AS l1
 ON Loty.MiejsceOdlotu = l1.LotniskoID
JOIN Lotnisko as l2
 ON Loty.MiejscePrzylotu = l2.LotniskoID
WHERE NumerLotu = 'KL1995'`

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to:

```
select 
   t1.Numer_Lotu as [Numer Lotu],
   t1.Miejsce_Odlotu as [Miejsce Odlotu],
   t2.Miejsce_Przylotu as [Miejsce Przylotu]
from

  (select Loty.NumerLotu as Numer_Lotu, Lotnisko.Nazwa as Miejsce_Odlotu
  from Loty
  JOIN Lotnisko on Loty.MiejsceOdlotu = Lotnisko.LotniskoID
  where NumerLotu = 'KL1995') t1

join

  (select Loty.NumerLotu as Numer_Lotu, Lotnisko.Nazwa as Miejsce_Przylotu
  from Loty
  JOIN Lotnisko on Loty.MiejscePrzylotu = Lotnisko.LotniskoID
  where NumerLotu = 'KL1995') t2
  
on t1.Numer_Lotu = t2.Numer_Lotu
```

Comment: After adding "(" before second select it's showing me that https://prnt.sc/26k6sp5

Comment: Yes, a parenthesis was left. I corrected the answer. Try again

Comment: There's no need for the many sub-queries. A single query with two joins will be significantly quicker and less memory intensive. Should also make it easier for the `WHERE` clause to be removed/updated.